# Reading from SQL and passing it to C# method

Tags: ssis

I need to read a column from a database table depending upon some parameter.  If the database table has two columns, status and ID, then I have to read the ID if the status is true.  Then I have to pass this ID to a C# method.

How can I achieve this in SSIS?  So basically my database package will read the data from SQL Server and pass it to a C# method.

Comment: what does Entity framework means. I want to do this is ssis..

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is an ETL Tool for moving and transforming large quantities of data.  If you need to do a lot of C# work and you only have one record, or a few records, SSIS may not be the right tool for this purpose.  You might do better writing an ASP.NET web application or a Windows application.  These applications can also use SQL to get data for processing in C#.

If you are determined to do this in SSIS and C#, here are two possible approaches:

1. You could use an [Execute SQL Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) to perform your query and save the rowset into a variable.  Then you would use a C# [Script Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141752.aspx) to do something with the contents of the variable.
2. You could create a [Data Flow Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx).  The dataflow should have the structure Source -> Transformation -> Destination, and can include several transformation components.

You would use, for example, an [OLE DB Source Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx) to perform your query.  Then you would use a C# [Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640.aspx) to transform each record that is returned by the query.  Finally, you would use a [OLE DB Destination Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx) to do something with the output for each record.